# How to deploy a contract from a different account (using truffle)

Tags: truffle

I want to use an account different than the default account to deploy a contract.

I'm looking for the equivalent of ethers connect() function and I can't seem to find it.

Currently deploying like so `contract = await Contract.new()` and I'm just looking for a way to specify the deploying account.

Does truffle have that option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Truffle when calling a transaction the last parameter has an optional dictionary with the transaction's parameters. For example something like this should work:

```
contract = await Contract.new(
  param1,
  ..more params..,
  { 
    from: "0xaabbccdd.....eeff",
    gas: "1234567",
  })
```

For more details see the [documentation](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/develop/packages/contract#mycontractnewarg1-arg2--tx-params).

Comment: What would that look like if I want to send parameters to the contract as well? 
For example, instead of Contract.new(addr)

Comment: @RoyToledo I've edited the answer to include parameters.

Comment: Nice. Even better 